# Why a recursive code does not print the None branches?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I did a recursive function that works, which usually what people want :)

But, as it goes through the "tree" of options, I'm wondering why it does not print the None branches.

The graph :

```
g = {
    "a" : ['c'],
    "b" : ['c'],
    "c" : ['a', 'b', 'e', 'd'],
    'd' : ['c'],
    'e' : ['c', 'b', 'g'],
    'f' : ['g'],
    'g' : ['f'],
}
```

The function :

```
def find_path(self, start_vertex, end_vertex, path=[]):
    graph = self.__graph_dict
    path.append(start_vertex)

    if end_vertex == start_vertex:
        return path

    for neighbour in graph[start_vertex]:
        if neighbour not in path:   
            extended_path = self.find_path(neighbour, end_vertex, path)

            if extended_path:
                return extended_path

    return None
```

The case that I do not understand is when neighbour is in the path and it return None.

```
print(self.find_path(a,f))
>> ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'f']
```

Comment: What's a `None` branch?

Comment: @recursive In this case, a None branch would be a path where 'a' does not meet 'f'. Ex.: If I go from 'a' to 'c' to 'd' I won't reach 'f' (you can't go backward). I call it a "branch" because it goes through that path. I don't know if there's a better way to explain it. Does "invalid" branch would be more appropriate?

Comment: Why would it print the wrong solutions?

Comment: @ReutSharabani Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I think your example is slightly off. Either 'b' should have an e instead of a c, add a c after the b in the path, or or leave 'b' out of the path. right now it's going from b to e and that path doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understand your question from the comments it's: "why are wrong paths not printed?". The answer is that they were eliminated.

For example the first path that's looked it is a **potential** loop `a-c-a-c-a-c`, but it's never fully iterated because of the short circuit:

```
if neighbour not in path:   # prevents loops
```

If you remove the pass from `a` to `c` you'll see that a dead end will return `None`. You currently don't have a dead end before you find the right path.

As for your code, I believe you want to create a new list for each recursion frame, since lists are mutable and you're mutating the `path` list possibly by two independent frames cause inconsistencies:

```
graph = self.__graph_dict
# path.append(start_vertex) # this was wrong
path = path += [start_vertex]
```

This way a new list is generated for each option. You solution in the answer:

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'f']
```

Is actually wrong and should have been:

```
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'f']
```

Comment: True, and thanks for "you're mutating list possibly"

Answer (score 0):

It never reaches the `return None`.

What I did not understand was that it keeps going through the tree only when the correct condition are meant.

At `a` and `b` the loops keep on looping until it defines an `extended_path`. If there's no such path, and only then, it returns `None`.